# Selenium and Python 3: selecting a search box on otto.de

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Python 3 as well as web scraping and I am a bit stuck right now.
I want to:
1. Select the search box on otto.de.
2. Insert the product number I want to search for.
3. Press enter or click the search button.
4. Download the following page.

The search field on otto.de has the following source code:

```
<form class="p_form js_searchForm focus" action="/suche" data-article-number-search="/p/search/" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" role="search">
            <input placeholder="Suchbegriff / Artikelnr. eingeben" data-error="Bitte mind. ein Zeichen eingeben" class="p_form__input js_searchField sanSearchInput" type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" maxlength="50" disabled>
            <button class="sanSearchDelBtn p_symbolBtn100--4th" type="reset"><i>X</i></button>
            <button class="js_submitButton sanSearchButton" type="submit" title="Suche" disabled ><span>&raquo;</span></button>
</form>
```

What I tried to do:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.otto.de')
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//form[input/@class='p_form__input   js_searchField sanSearchInput']")
elem.send_keys('538707' + Keys.RETURN)
with open("Productpage.txt", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(browser.page_source)
browser.quit()
```

It gives me the following error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Message: Unable    to clear element that cannot be edited: <form class=
"p_form js_searchForm focus">
```

I tried many different commands but I just can't get on the page I need. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to click on it before sending keys?

Comment: Sounds like your xpath selects the <form> element. What you really want to select (to later send keys to) is the <input> element inside the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.otto.de")

ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".p_form__input.js_searchField.sanSearchInput"))).send_keys("538707")

ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".js_submitButton.sanSearchButton"))).click()

with open("Productpage.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as outfile:

    outfile.write(browser.page_source)

time.sleep(5)

browser.quit()
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks you very much, that helps a lot!!

Comment: Ok, great! Check a tick near my answer, please.

Comment: Just to understand your code better: Why do you use WebDriverWait and sleep? Is the waiting time needed to find the element and save the page content?

Comment: 1) `WebDriverWait` is used for locating (finding) element. This is an explicit wait. 2) `time.sleep(5)` can be removed. It just to see results in the end.